# What does « J'ai la course à faire » mean ?

Tags: sens, usage

Watching tv and a character says "*j'ai la course à faire*" (but she was not going to run anywhere) and she was not going shopping.

Can it mean I have something to go and do?

Comment: Please add some context.

Comment: Weird French but maybe: *I need to do it*.

Comment: *faire la course* = race someone, *faire une course* = run an errand, *faire les courses* = do the groceries.

Answer (score 4):

*J'ai la course à faire* does not sound like proper french.

*J'ai une course à faire* can indeed be used to say go shopping but has a more broader meaning. For example, it's ok to use it when you go to the postoffice, to the hairdresser, if you have to go pickup something,...

It's also quite a generic expression that can be used as an excuse to leave if you do not want to say specally where you are going.

Please provide more context if you want a more precise answer.

Comment: The making an excuse to go elsewhere seems to fit the situation I saw in the tv programme.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Ndech's response, it seems the most accurate translation of *j'ai une course à faire* would be *I have an errand to run*. It is possible then, if the character on the TV program in your question referred to the errand in an earlier sentence, that they could use *la course* to refer to the errand previously mentioned.